# PowerBI - DAX (Find previous time in filtered area and return value from other column)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am struggling with a task in DAX.

To achieve (yellow column):
Find previous datetime value in filtered scope and return value from other column. I would like to have a ID (MOVE_ID), instead of time of previous move, which is working fine, as below. 
Already achieved (green column - working correctly):
I was able to return the value itself (MAX function as below). I was trying to change from yesterday to meet my requirements, without success. I assume it is quite trivial, but skill is missing :)

```
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(TABLE1[Move_TIME]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(TABLE1),
            TABLE1[Move_EQ] = EARLIER(TABLE1[Move_EQ])  
            && TABLE1[Move_EQ] <> BLANK()
            && [TABLE1Move_TIME] < EARLIER(TABLE1[Move_TIME])
        )
    )
```

| Move_ID | Move_EQ | Move_TIME | Move_TIME_OF_PREVIOUS_MOVE | Move_ID_OF_PREVIOUS_MOVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EQ1 | 2021-12-13 11:02:14 |  | null |
| 2 | EQ1 | 2021-12-13 11:03:01 | 2021-12-13 11:02:14 | 1 |
| 3 | EQ2 | 2021-12-13 11:15:33 |  | null |
| 4 | EQ1 | 2021-12-13 13:12:00 | 2021-12-13 11:03:01 | 2 |
| 5 | EQ2 | 2021-12-13 14:00:00 | 2021-12-13 11:15:33 | 3 |
| 6 | EQ2 | 2021-12-13 14:01:00 | 2021-12-13 14:00:00 | 5 |
| 7 | EQ1 | 2021-12-13 14:32:11 | 2021-12-13 13:12:00 | 4 |
| 8 | EQ1 | 2021-12-13 14:44:54 | 2021-12-13 14:32:11 | 7 |
| 9 | EQ1 | 2021-12-13 14:45:01 | 2021-12-13 14:44:54 | 8 |
| 10 | EQ1 | 2021-12-13 15:01:09 | 2021-12-13 14:45:01 | 9 |

[image: SampleTable]
Thank You in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide the data in a table format here [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a measure like this

```
Measure =
VAR _current =
    MAX ( 'transaction'[Move_Time] )
VAR _eq =
    MAX ( 'transaction'[Move_EQ] )
VAR _immediatelyPrecedingDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'transaction'[Move_Time] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'transaction' ), 'transaction'[Move_Time] < _current ),
        'transaction'[Move_EQ] = _eq
    )
VAR _id =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'transaction'[Move_ID] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'transaction' ),
            'transaction'[Move_Time] = _immediatelyPrecedingDate
                && 'transaction'[Move_EQ] = _eq
        )
    )
RETURN
    _id
```

[image: Solution]

or if you prefer a calculated column, you can take advantage of already created column to create the new column

```
Move_ID_OF_PREVIOUS_MOVE =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'transaction'[Move_ID] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'transaction' ),
        'transaction'[Move_EQ] = EARLIER ( 'transaction'[Move_EQ] )
            && 'transaction'[Move_EQ] <> BLANK ()
            && 'transaction'[Move_Time] = EARLIER ( 'transaction'[Move_TIME_OF_PREVIOUS_MOVE] )
    )
)
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank You very much :) 
Can You please explain, why MAX( 'transaction'[MOVE_ID] ) is working correctly in that calculation? MOVE_ID can be text value (i checked it) and still works. I was trying with VALUES there which did not work, which looks more "appropriate" ... but does not work :)

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer. By using `ALL` all the filters from the tables were  removed, then the partitions were explicitly mentioned, and within that partition it brings the `MAX` value. DAX engine stores the text value based on the `CHAR` number and `MAX` retuns MAX of the CHAR number which is why it works.

Comment: Well noted. Thanks once again, have a good evening/day :)